# Spring boot -Whitelabel Error Page Local host

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, localhost

I have set up my request controller and rest mapping but I am receiving 'Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Mar 11 20:28:19 GMT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available' when I use the url http://localhost:8080/hello .

It was working a week ago. I have the correct dependency and I have tried component scan base package in my app.java and moving the controller to the same package as the app.java.  Ive attached my package explorer and below is my code

```
package com.fyp.reviewchecker.Controller;

import   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
 public class SearchController {

@RequestMapping("/hello") public String hello() {
    return "Hello\n";
    }

}


package com.fyp.reviewchecker;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication

@EnableJpaAuditing

public class ReviewcheckerApplication implements    CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ReviewcheckerApplication.class, args);
}
@Override
 public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO contact_table (name, subject, message, email, phone) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ";
    int result = jdbcTemplate.update(sql,  "kirsty", "Complaint", "Love it", "Kirstenlivs@gmail.com", "07429");
    
    if (result > 0) {
        System.out.println("contact form updated");
    }
        
        
        
      }

}
```

[package explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z9ya.png)

Answer (score 0):

- first avoid using **@RequestMapping** use **@PostMapping, @GetMapping** etc
  instead.
- check if you have configuration in your property files like this:

  **server.servlet.context**
- to check if the controller is being scanned by spring or not, you can try using **applicationContext.getBeansOfType(SearchController.class);** in your main/commandLineRunner or by using a **@PostConstruct** in the **SearchController** with some logging in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It was nothing to do with my code I had a 'missing' Jar file that I hadn't disposed of properly so my project wouldn't build until I had it. I added the jar file back and deleted it and now it works.